# RMI ClassNotFoundException _Stub

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I've been trying multiple variations of this and have not succeeded at all.  The following is what I'm writing on the command-line to start the RMI Server.  I've started the rmiregistry while in the same folder (/usr/local/shared/.../RMIServer) and try to run the command below but still get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FileDiscovery_Stub

```
java -Djava.security.policy=security.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/usr/local/shared/.../RMIServer/RMIFTServer.jar -jar RMIFTServer.jar
```

The jar file for the RMIServer is in the same folder (/usr/local/shared.../RMIServer) as well as the security.policy file needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have a stub, you're doing it wrong.  try an updated rmi tutorial.  it should not mention anything about rmic, skeletons, or stubs.

Comment: had to do it that way for a class I'm currently taking

Answer (score 0):

Don't start the RMI registry in the same folder as the server. You don't want it to use the server's CLASSPATH, you want it to rely on the codebase feature.

Your class is out of date. If you specify port zero when exporting or constructing your remote object, you won't need a _Stub at all.